# How to register an array in javascript from a different code section than Page_Load with ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm using the following code in my aspx.cs file:

```
    String arrName = "MyArray";
    String arrValue = "\"1\", \"2\", \"text\"";

    // Define the hidden field name and initial value.
    String hiddenName = "MyHiddenField";
    String hiddenValue = "3";


    // Get a ClientScriptManager reference from the Page class.
    ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

    // Register the array with the Page class.
    cs.RegisterArrayDeclaration(arrName, arrValue);

    // Register the hidden field with the Page class.
    cs.RegisterHiddenField(hiddenName, hiddenValue);
```

This is the code from client

```
function onClick(rowIndex, cellIndex) 
{             
    alert(MyArray[0]);
}
```

And if I try to retrieve on javascript any value of MyArray I can do it without problems if this code is into the Page_Load section of code, but if I try to call it from other place of the code, from the one I have to call from, although the code executes it seems that registering of the array is being ignored as I get an error when I try to get any of the results from MyArray in javascript.

I find this error pretty strange but it's what's happening... Can you try to figure out what might be happening, please?

Comment: You haven't told us what the error is. That seems like a very important detail if you want us to explain why it's happening. You also haven't shown any of your client side script to explain where the error is occurring.

Comment: Error is that MyArray is not defined, the code is only the little code I've put now.If called from OnLoad it displays 1, but if called from other region it gives that error.

Comment: Where are you calling the `RegisterArrayDeclaration` from?

Comment: I've to call it from a function I've developed on my own, if called from Page_Load it works.

Comment: @mylket So your function that you developed probably isn't called at all when the page is first requested, and therefore your array isn't registered.

Comment: Yeah, it's not. But I can't register the array previous to calling that function as its content is generated after Page_Load. I find this limitation a bit strange and in documentation it doesn't say anything about only working in Page_Load. In fact @Segev Davan has run the code without it.

Answer (score 0):

well,I been running your code successfully although your problem not entirely clear to me:

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm3.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test.WebForm3" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>ClientScriptManager Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">
        <input type="text" id="Message" />
        <input type="button" onclick="onClick()" value="Run Script" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    </form>
    <script>
        function onClick(rowIndex, cellIndex) {
                alert(MyArray[0]);
            }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class WebForm3 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          String arrName = "MyArray";
    String arrValue = "\"1\", \"2\", \"text\"";

    // Define the hidden field name and initial value.
    String hiddenName = "MyHiddenField";
    String hiddenValue = "3";


    // Get a ClientScriptManager reference from the Page class.
    ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

    // Register the array with the Page class.
    cs.RegisterArrayDeclaration(arrName, arrValue);

    // Register the hidden field with the Page class.
    cs.RegisterHiddenField(hiddenName, hiddenValue);
            }
        }
    }
```

have to run the code by button click and then it work

Comment: maybe your problem was that you try to use code that you didn't yet run?

Comment: It's not, I entered debug mode and checked it ran. Thanks for your tip.